Ffmpeg - How to remove only one tag from the mp3 track output?
I need to remove the lyrics tag from my output track.
Track information:
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:1 -> #0:0 (copy) 
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:1 (mp3 (mp3float) -> mp3 (libmp3lame))  
Output #0, mp3, to 'D:\My_music\Music_no_lyrics.mp3':
  Metadata:
    TIT2        : Music

    lyrics-eng  :                            _
                :                             |
                :                             |
                :                             |  I want remove this tag
                :                             |
                : musics.org                 _|    
                                             
     TALB       : Classic Musics
     TCON       : Classic
     TPE1       : Music
     TSSE       : Lavf59.17.102

My command:
ffmpeg -hide_banner -i "D:\My_music\Music.mp3" -c:v copy -id3v2_version 3 -metadata lyrics-eng="" -acodec mp3 -b:a 320 -ar:a 44100 "D:\My_music\Music_no_lyrics.mp3"

How can I do this?

ExifTool is more suitable for this

This is somewhat complicated.  The problem is you want to remove the tag completely, and it's a custom tag, so complete removal will require stripping every tag.
You can save the current tags:
ffmpeg -i your_file.mp3 -an -f ffmetadata md_save.txt

This will remove them:
ffmpeg -i your_file.mp3 -c:a copy -map_metadata -1 your_file_no_tags.mp3

If you have a lot of files to process, you will need to incorporate sed or awk, grep...something to remove the lyrics-eng line from the md_save.txt for the custom tag.  If you don't have very many files, you can just open it in a text editor and delete that line.
Then you can add the tags back with:
ffmpeg -i your_file.mp3 -c:a copy -i md_save.txt -map_metadata 1 -id3v2_version 3 your_file_final.mp3

ID3 tags have always been an adventure.Hope this helps!

Hi Jay... My System is Windows 10 and I use a bat file to process a lot of files! How do I remove everything from the txt file that is "different" from ;FFMETADATA1 title= and encoder= ?

You are trying to stream edit, like sed on linux?  (Get-Content c:\path\to\your_file.txt).replace('[MYID]', 'MyValue') | Set-Content c:\path\to\your_file.txt

I don't understand your answer!?, it's confusing to me!

@Clamarc This will explain it much better for you.

I am going to try.
